# Server unreachable after hot module replacement (Webpack)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-hmr

when I make a change, i see this in terminal:

```
[1] [piping] File src/containers/Blocks/Blocks.js has changed, reloading.
[0] webpack building...
[0] webpack built 67cf99a9b98c59d668ed in 3497ms
```

But after this, I cant do anything anymore, if I refresh I see this:

```
GET http://blokdemo.localhost:3000/dashboard net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

It used to work but since I updated from this:

```
"webpack": "^1.12.9",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.4.0",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.5.0"
```

to this:

```
"webpack": "^1.13.0",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0",
"webpack-isomorphic-tools": "^2.2.50"
```

It does not work anymore.

these are the 2 commands I use to run:

```
  "start-dev": {
      "command": "node ./bin/server.js",
      "env": {
        "NODE_PATH": "./src",
        "NODE_ENV": "development",
        "PORT": 3000,
        "APIHOST": "http://localhost:3333"
      }
    },
    "watch-client": {
      "command": "node webpack/webpack-dev-server.js",
      "env": {
        "UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE": 100,
        "NODE_PATH": "./src",
        "PORT": 3000
      }
    }
```

this is the link to my dev.config: [dev config](https://gist.github.com/feesjah/490c3938b879505bddd0a2d939204c65)

Any idea what might be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the command you use to run it?

Comment: done, also added link to dev config